# $lookup seems to match null as lookup information

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-lookup

I have the following lookup and gives me strange results for documents who do not have an id_bidon. It's like it defaults to null and is matched to the first document who doesn't have a id_client_bidon. Is there a way around this?

```
{
  from: 'book',
  localField: 'id_bidon',
  foreignField: 'id_client_bidon',
  as: 'client'
}
```

Edit (2019-02-04) : If a document in my collection doesn't have a id_bidon, it will be considered null and will be linked to a book with an id_client_bidon that is null.

Comment: Add a `$match` stage in the beginning as `{ $match: { "id_bidon": { $exists: true }}}`.  If you're using >= 3.6, you can use "pipeline" to check id_client_bidon.

Comment: @simagix The problem with the match, is that it'll remove the documents. What if I want them even if they don't have related data in the other collection? I guess the problem would be solved if I forced every document to include a id_bidon, but I'm just playing around to see the limits of schemaless.